# Wave equation references.

Tags: reference-request

I´m searching information about the wave equation in partial differential equations:

$$U_{tt}-c^{2}\Delta U=0.$$
I need the history, deduction and interpretation, if someone could tell me some books where I can find this information will be awesome.

Comment: Lawrence C. Evans

Comment: See also [Wave equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wave_equation).